# Get single xpub key from multi signature wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, multi-signature

I created a multi signature wallet 2 of 3. I want to get the xpub key used to generate the addresses. As I understand all 3 public keys are used to generate the address. Is it possible to use those 3 keys to generate a single xpub key for further addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get a single public seed for all future addresses.

Let's say you have three private seeds, `Sa`, `Sb` and `Sc` with public seeds (xpubs) `Pa`, `Pb` and `Pc` that generate the addresses `Px1`, `Px2`, ...

Then, the way to calculate the multi-sig addresses for a 2-of-3 multisig for these three seeds using [P2SH](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/p2sh-address) is the following:

You create a P2SH redeem script that looks as follows:

```
OP_2 [Pa1] [Pb1] [Pc1] OP_3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

Then, the "multisig address" is the RIPEMD-160 hash of that script.

Thus, to know the next address, you will need to calculate a new RIPEMD-160 hash with the script now containing `Pa2`, `Pb2` and `Pc2`. There is not a multi-seed of any kind.